# Подскажите как передать значение наз. спойлера из БД

Tags: php, javascript, yii, json

```
<div>
<div class="spoiler-title closed"> <?php echo "Розгорнути відгук про навчання &#9660" ?></div>
    <div class="spoiler-body">
            <img src="<?php echo StaticFilesHelper::createPath('image', 'graduates', "recall.png"); ?>">
            <?php echo $data['recall'] ?>
     </div>
</div>
```

Использую данный скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.spoiler-body').hide();
    $('.spoiler-title').click(function(){

        $(this).toggleClass('opened').toggleClass('closed').next().slideToggle();
        if($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
            $(this).html('Згорнути відгук  про навчання \u25B2');
        }
        else {
            $(this).html('Розгорнути відгук про навчання \u25BC');
        }
    });
});
```

Название спойлера нужно брать из БД `<?php echo Yii::t('блабла', '№стр.') ?>`.

**Обновление**

При клике на `<?php echo "Розгорнути відгук про навчання &#9660" ?></div>`, заполнянолось из БД `<?php echo Yii::t('блабла', '123') ?>`, передавались значение из БД в js `$(this).html('Згорнути відгук  про навчання \u25B2');` и `$(this).html('Розгорнути відгук про навчання \u25BC');`

Comment: можете объяснить ситуацию. не полностью понял вопрос. Вы хотите, что бы при клине ка `title` заполнялось `body` из БД?

Comment: как передать значение из файла *.php в  файл *.js

Answer (score 1):

нужно сделать 2 вещи,

1. на стороне php создайте `controller` и `function` для обработки какой то ссылки. Внутри функции делаете действия

   ```
   echo Yii::t('блабла', '123')
   ```
2. Теперь на стороне `js` файла

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {

     $(".spoiler-title").on('click', function () {

       requestHtml = $.ajax({
           url: 'ссылка на контроллнр/функция/' + 'строка с параметрами',
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "html"
       });

       requestHtml.done(function (respose, status, xhr) {
          // тут можно и проверки ставить как вам нужно. 
          // А так если проверки большые делайте в php стороне
          $('div.spoiler-body').html(response);
       });
     });
   });
   ```

можно использовать также `dataType: "json"` вместо `dataType: "html"` и обработать как нужно

думаю это поможет

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.